# How to create a frequency / value count table from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes,

```
df1                       df2
country                   country
US                        AR
US                        AD
CA                        AO
CN                        AU
AR                        US
```

How do I group by them by combining the country list to a set the compare the difference between two dataframes?

My expected output will be like,

```
country code   df1_country_count   df2_country_count
AR                   1                    1
AD                   0                    1
AO                   0                    1
AU                   0                    1
US                   2                    1 
CA                   1                    0
CN                   1                    0
```

Comment: 1) combine all the dataframes and assign a column identify the source: `df = pd.concat([d.assign(source=f'df{i}') for i, d in enumerate([df1, df2], 1)], ignore_index=True)` 2) use `pd.crosstab`: `counts = pd.crosstab(df.country, df.source)`. This option is simple, and works regardless of the number of sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(df1.value_counts().to_frame('df1_country_count')
 .join(df2.value_counts().to_frame('df2_country_count'), how='outer')
 .fillna(0).astype('int').rename_axis('country code'))
```

result:

```
               df1_country_count    df2_country_count
country code        
AD             0                    1
AO             0                    1
AR             1                    1
AU             0                    1
CA             1                    0
CN             1                    0
US             2                    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value_counts` and then concat.

```
out = pd.concat([df1.country.value_counts(), 
           df2.country.value_counts()], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
out.columns = ['df1_country', 'df2_country']
print(out)

    df1_country  df2_country
US            2            1
CA            1            0
CN            1            0
AR            1            1
AD            0            1
AO            0            1
AU            0            1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Combine all of the dataframes, regardless of how many, with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and use [`.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) in a list comprehension to add a `'source'` column.

   - `source=f'df{i}'`: structure the f-string for how the column name should appear in the frequency table.
   - If loading the data from files, see **Option 4** of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) to load the csv files directly into a single dataframe with a new column.
2. Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to compute a frequency table of the two columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['US', 'US', 'CA', 'CN', 'AR']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['AR', 'AD', 'AO', 'AU', 'US']})

# list of dataframes
df_list = [df1, df2]

# combine dataframes
df = pd.concat([d.assign(source=f'df{i}') for i, d in enumerate(df_list, 1)], ignore_index=True)

# create frequency table
counts = pd.crosstab(df.country, df.source)

source   df1  df2
country          
AD         0    1
AO         0    1
AR         1    1
AU         0    1
CA         1    0
CN         1    0
US         2    1
```